# Stop Powershell Script if disk size is less than X

Tags: powershell, disk, diskspace

I wonder if you could help me out guys.
I need to stop a powershell script if the disk size of partition E is less than 10GB, and to continue if it´s more than 10GB.

So far i managed to get my disk size listed with this.

`Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | Format-Table DeviceId,@{n="FreeSpace";e={[math]::Round($_.FreeSpace/1GB,2)}}`

And i get this result:

| DeviceId | Freespace |
| --- | --- |
| A | 0 |
| C | 77.9 |
| D | 0 |
| E | 34.05 |

So, i want to stop the powershell script if E unit has less than 10GB.
How can i do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you checking for disk size, or free space?  For example, disk size might be 500 GB with a free space of only 5 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put the Freespace of E in a variable you can do this :

```
$VarSpace = $(Get-WmiObject -Class win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object -Property Name -eq C:).FreeSpace/1GB
```

then you can do a simple if for check :

```
if ($VarSpace -le 10){ <Something for stopping you script like exit> }
```

Comment: your answer worked for me, but i have to change -Property Name for DeviceId.

Comment: How can i make the same question but for a diferent pc?

Comment: I don't really know but you can try to use `Set-Service -Name WinRm -ComputerName <pcname> -Status Running`
Then connect to the pc with : `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName <pcname>`
I think this could help you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Get-Volume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/get-volume) cmdlet for that or `Get-CimInstance`rather than the old `Get-WmiObject`:

```
$freeOnE = (Get-CimInstance -ClassName win32_logicaldisk | Where-Object {$_.DeviceID -eq 'E:'}).FreeSpace / 1GB
```

or

```
$freeOnE = (Get-Volume -DriveLetter E).SizeRemaining / 1GB
```

Then exit your PowerShell session if this value is below 10Gb

```
if ($freeOnE -lt 10) { exit }
```